# Как задать высоту дочернего блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Хочу сделать оверлей для картинки. Придумал такую верстку:

```
<div id="parent">
  <img/>
  <div id="children"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
img {width: 100%;}
```

Подскажите, как задать высоту div#children, что бы она была равна высоте ?

Comment: Желательно без скриптов.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/xd922vb9/

Comment: @soledar10, спасибо! Если оформите как ответ - поставлю галочку )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.parent {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}
.children {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.parent:hover .children{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" alt="">
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: какую роль тут играет line-height?

Comment: для того чтобы убрать отступ img. при наведении это будет видно https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/rwgu3x44/

Comment: как вариант можно img добавить display:block; - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/kmh0vbgt/